# Add extra string value to Dictionary/Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a function that get all friends online, now I want to add an extra value called **ProfilePic** to the Json string.

With the code below i get the friend id. 
ProfilePic value is in the UserDTO and the column name in the database is ProfilePic

My problem is that i dont know how to get that value in the json string.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        // Init db
        Db db = new Db();

        // Get user id
        UserDTO userDTO = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(Context.User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
        int userId = userDTO.Id;


        // Get all online ids
        List<int> onlineIds = db.Online.ToArray().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

        // Get friends ids
        List<int> friendIds1 = db.Friends.Where(x => x.User1 == userId && x.Active == true).ToArray().Select(x => x.User2).ToList();

        List<int> friendIds2 = db.Friends.Where(x => x.User2 == userId && x.Active == true).ToArray().Select(x => x.User1).ToList();

        List<int> allFriendsIds = friendIds1.Concat(friendIds2).ToList();


        // Get final set of ids
        List<int> resultList = onlineIds.Where((i) => allFriendsIds.Contains(i)).ToList();

        // Create a dict of friend ids and usernames
        Dictionary<int, string> dictFriends = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (var id in resultList)
        {
            var users = db.Users.Find(id);
            string friend = users.Username;


            string ProfilePic = users.ProfilePic;

            if (!dictFriends.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                dictFriends.Add(id, friend);
            }
        }

        var transformed = from key in dictFriends.Keys
                          select new { id = key, friend = dictFriends[key], ProfilePic = "VALUE HERE" };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformed);

        // Set Clients
        var clients = Clients.Caller;

        // Call js function
        clients.getonlinefriends(Context.User.Identity.Name, json);

        // Return
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: I dont know how to pass the ProfilePic value to the json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is you aren't recording all of you database information into the same object.  You are trying to put too much information into a single key-value paired dictionary.  Instead, you should make a helper class to better represent the model you are returning to the client.  For example:

```
public class UserJson
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string ProfilePic {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your loop where you query your database, just create those objects and `JsonConvert` afterwards:

```
var userList = new List<UserJson>();
foreach (var id in resultList)
{
    var users = db.Users.Find(id);
    string friend = users.Username;
    string profilePic = users.ProfilePic;

    userList.Add(new UserJson {Name = friend, Id = id, ProfilePic = profilePic });
}
string json = JsonConvert(userList);
```

Or if you *really* don't want to create a helper class, you can use a `List<dynamic>` anonymous objects.  But having the helper class helps better encapsulate your code (for example validation code).

[Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sjb2ms)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple instead of a dictionary.

from msdn:
[Tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Create a 7-tuple.
var population = new Tuple<string, int, int, int, int, int, int>(
                           "New York", 7891957, 7781984, 
                           7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
// Display the first and last elements.
Console.WriteLine("Population of {0} in 2000: {1:N0}",
                  population.Item1, population.Item7);
// The example displays the following output:
// Population of New York in 2000: 8,008,278
```

in your case it would be

```
List<Tuple<int, string, string>>
```

You could also create an class to hold the results.